# What to give as close reason if the "Question" is simply not a question?

Tags: discussion

[Why is it always either “there is no God”, or “God exists and is good”?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/75756/why-is-it-always-either-there-is-no-god-or-god-exists-and-is-good) is not a question - it looks like it is meant as an answer to [Why is it always either "there is no God", or "God exists and is good"? Are Christians entirely closed to the idea of God being evil?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/75755/why-is-it-always-either-there-is-no-god-or-god-exists-and-is-good-are-chri)

I would like to vote for closing, but I didn't find a close reason "not a question". Just to double check that this is not specific to Christianity.SE, I looked on StackOverflow and also didn't find such an option. I know you can flag answers as "Not an answer", but what about Questions? What is the right way to handle questions that aren't really questions?

Comment: They are opinion based. That is to say they exist in order to spread an opinion.

Comment: @NigelJ I see, but I think opinion-based is more meant when the answers are going to be opinion-based (due to the scope of the question for example), instead of objective. Like Truth questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I normally close non-questions as "Needs details or clarity", because as it says, "it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking" when you're not asking a question.

Comment: It is a no brainer to say the least! +1.

Answer (score 0):

"General philosophy" for the questions you link. To Christians, it is a question of *worthiness*. If God is not perfect and holy, then he is not worthy of worship, thus the religion falls apart. Indeed, "worthy of worship" is the central point of all the big monotheist religions. Arguments outside of that context are general philosophy and are no longer about Christianity. Monotheists certainly have a voice in the divine existential question, but it is steadfastly fixed into this very specific context. You have to keep it in that context when asking questions here, or it becomes a general philosophy question.

Now, I think [the second question you link](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/75755/why-is-it-always-either-there-is-no-god-or-god-exists-and-is-good-are-chri) has some hope to be a pretty good question. I'd change it by quoting Lewis. He wrote on this topic a lot, especially in *Mere Christianity*. Within that work is Lewis' philosophy on why that third option ("There is a God, but he is unfortunately evil") cannot mutually exist with Christianity. Keeping the question in context of Lewis' writings and philosophies, I think, would be acceptable here, because he's basically a Christian household name and scoping to well-known Christian theologians and thinkers has always been allowed here.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I was asking specifically about the first one. The second one is a question at least.